# Plank icon zoom not available in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: plank

After installing plank on Ubuntu 19.04 and the plank settings app, there is no setting to allow icon zoom.  Is there a fix for this? or am I missing something?

Comment: It's there for me by default in 19.04. Don't you see a Plank icon in the dock? That has settings for the icon zoom feature. Perhaps it's turned off on your system?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImieW.png

Comment: That's just it, I don't see that option in my settings window.

Comment: I had to remove Plank, and install from Ricotz PPA...now I see the icon zoom option in preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS. I solved it by purging `plank`.

1. Remove all packages related to `plank`
   `apt purge plank libplank1 libplank-common`
2. Fresh install `plank`
   `apt-get install plank`

This should fix your problem.